# Logic App Request Trigger always returning content-type equal to 0

Tags: api, request, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to set up HTTP Request triggered logic app, using my webhook.

The head received by the request in logic app (output) is the following :

```
{
    "headers": {
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip; q=1.0,deflate; q=0.6,identity; q=0.3",
        "Host": "prod-23.westus.logic.azure.com",
        "User-Agent": "AgentID,
        "X-Looker-Webhook-Token": "securitytoken",
        "X-Looker-Instance": "instanceid",
        "X-Looker-Webhook-Id": "webhookid",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": "0"
    }
}
```

Always receiving Content-Lenght, when I do the exacte same request using Postman it works just fine.

I'm suspecting the chunked encoding, but tried with webhook.site, all the data is received at once and not in multiples chunk.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the HTTP trigger in logic apps does not support 'chunked' transfer encoding.

You can vote [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/33616297-implement-chunked-transfer-encoding-inside-logic-a)

If you call the logic app from a C# app, you should not use the `PostAsJsonAsync` extension method. Instead, use `StringContent` or `ByteArrayContent` with the `PostAsync` call.